# What tables does QODBC's SP_Report pull from?

Tags: sql, quickbooks, qodbc

I have the following query that was used by someone else and we are now using a sync tool to pull data straight out of QB and into SQL.  So now I have all of the tables that I can query, but I'm trying to figure out what tables this query pulls from.  Any help?

```
;sp_report TxnDetailByAccount show TxnID, AccountListID, Amount, 
Text, Class, TxnType, Date as TransactionDate, RefNumber, Name, Memo
```

Answer (score 2):

QODBC is an ODBC driver (DLL) for QuickBooks Accounting format files. QuickBooks Accounting stores its data in its own proprietary DBMS file format. This driver allows users of any ODBC compliant front end application to read and write data contained in QuickBooks Accounting format files similarly to any other ODBC enabled database.

QODBC works by accepting SQL commands from applications through the ODBC interface, then converting those calls to navigational XML commands to the QuickBooks Accounting DBMS and returning record sets that qualify for the query results. This driver is not a Client/Server product, but rather communicates directly with the QuickBooks application as it runs. QuickBooks is a flat file database, and this driver will not change it into a relational database, so keep that in mind when developing with this driver.

QODBC acts as a 'wrapper' around the Intuit SDK so customers can finally get at their QuickBooks data using standard database tools; speeding development time.

QuickBooks SDK does not expose information regarding how a report is built, what are the tables used or logic part and thus it is not available in QODBC.

You may try querying Transaction table and for details, you may have to link it with individual tables like InvoiceLine, BillExpenseLine etc.